# how to limit field pack list

Tags: field-pack

How do I limit the number of displayed list items? I tried {list_name limit='2'} which didn't work. Also is there anyway to select which list items to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot limit how many entries are returning from a Field Pack List field.

To filter the items displayed, you could do a conditional check on each item:

```
{list_name}
    {if item != "foo"}{item}{/if}
{/list_name}
```